# Chome extension prevents <select> elements from expanding

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a very simple Chome extension that exposes a single toolbar button. When the button is clicked, the page content is POSTed to the server using `XMLHttpRequest` and then the `innerHtml` of the **<html>** element is replaced by the new content returned from the server.

For some reason this prevents **<select>** elements from expanding. I have verified this by disabling the extension which makes then work again.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to fix it? The code is below for reference:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.msg == "get_content") {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML =
                       xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert('Cannot reach russiangram.com');
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://russiangram.com/translate/Default.aspx", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
        sendResponse({ data: 'success' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

At a guess I would say where you are replacing the contents of the documents HTML tag that you are possibly also replacing any associated JS/CSS references that were originally on that page as well.

Maybe as a test instead of replacing the contents of the HTML tag, add a new DIV element or something to the page and target that instead. That should hopefully allow you see whether or not the select functionality still works.